# What does "bad girls go backstage" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, pop-culture

(sorry for my poor English)

I saw this phrase somewhere but I don't know what this means..

> Good girls go to heaven, **bad girls go backstage**

What means '**bad girls go backstage**'?

Maybe.. it's when good girls try to be good, but bad girls become famous?
 Am I right?

Answer (score 31):

> Good girls go to heaven. Bad girls go backstage.

Constructions of this type have been termed a [*snowclone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone), meaning a cliché with at least one part that can be replaced at will. Basically, every iteration of the pattern suggests that bad girls have sex, in this case, like a rock groupie.

The most immediate ancestor of your expression is

> Good girls go to heaven. Bad girls go everywhere.

variously attributed to Mae West, but definitely popularized by feminist Helen Gurley Brown, though in a subversive sense that exposes the patriarchal convenience that bad girls are sluts. It also made its way into [song lyrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Girls_Go_to_Heaven_(Bad_Girls_Go_Everywhere)) by [Jim Steinman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Steinman) and covered by various artists.

The expression is actually a condensed joke, like [this one](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/08/19/good-bad-girls/), for instance, from 1900:

> A mother who was talking to her little girl the other evening was greatly surprised at the answer she received to one of her questions. “My child, where do good girls go when they die?” “To heaven, of course.” “My dear, where do bad girls go?” “To the depot to see the traveling men come in.”

While the first part is always fixed, the second may vary, and even drop any veiled allusion to sex.

[image]
[image]

This is a women’s t-shirt produced primarily for the [German market](https://www.spreadshirt.de/bad+girls+go+to+munich+oktoberfest-A59b658125fd3e416e3868165), but using the English snowclone. While most people go to the Oktoberfest to pay exhorbitant prices for draft beer, a *Wiesn-Liebschaft* is an affair usually assumed not to last much longer than the festival. The *Wiesn* lit. ‘meadow’ is the fairgrounds where the festival is held.
[image]

Comment: +1 But as to "every iteration of the pattern suggests that bad girls have sex" -- a variant popular when I was in high school in the early '60s was "Good girls put out; bad girls go with you to shoot rats at the city dump."

Comment: @StoneyB: you must have grown up in a really vibrant place. There is a larger pattern _good girls x; bad girls y_. My mother always said, "Good girls get pregnant; bad girls know what to do." The heavenward-directed good girls are a subgenre.

Comment: *"Basically, every iteration of the pattern suggests that bad girls have sex..."* That's not been my interpretation of it (native AmE speaker, string BrE influences [20 years in the UK], 51 years old). The sense I've always had was that bad girls go to places and do things that good girls don't, with the impression that bad girls are getting more out of life. That *may* involve having sex, but not necessarily. More that bad girls don't play by the rules that stereotype a "good girl" (which, again, can involve sex, or drinking, or staying out late, or...).

Comment: (err... that was meant to be "strong" not "string"...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: if the heaven-everywhere version weren't susceptible to an interpretation subversive of patriarchal sexual morality, then Helen Gurley Brown would hardly have been the one to discuss it. People go to the Oktoberfest mainly to drink beer, but a _Wiesn-Liebschaft_ is an affair begun at the Oktoberfest and likely not lasting much longer than the festival.

Comment: @KarlG: Citation for HGB *specifically* calling it out as meaning sex?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: How HGB recast this snowclone is quite peripheral to the question, but I've amended my answer to reflect that. Backstage bad girls have more in common with the 1900 depot-visiting bad girls than any sort of feminist subversion of a cliché.

Comment: Well, I didn't raise HGB, you did. It does indeed seem peripheral. Do you have any basis other than your opinion for it meaing, specifically, sex? As opposed to just rule-breaking behavior in general? (Genuinely curious, not just trying to be difficult.)

Comment: Did this answer the question?

Comment: @Lambie: I suppose I should have defined _groupie_ more precisely.

Comment: @KarlG No worries. It was the process I was referring to....

Answer (score 3):

Being invited "backstage" at a concert means that you are invited to meet the band before/after the show in the non-public areas of the venue, when they are preparing for the show or hanging out after the show.

This is considered a great privilege among fans, since that invitation has to either come from a band member, or from venue staff with the consent of a band member. It means you are either an established friend of theirs, or a stranger considered worth partying with in whatever manner; whether it is about talking, drinking, "groupie" behaviour, or whatever else does not matter here at all - if she is a fan, she will consider having a beer with the band a privilege (just as a male fan would); if she wants casual sex, she will see that as a privilege too; if both matter, so what. There can only be a limited number of members of the general public invited to do so at each concert, since backstage rooms tend to be small and cramped, and having too many people there would both be a security risk and ruin the semi-private atmosphere.

The whole comparison is about conventional ("heaven") vs subcultural ("backstage") success.

Comment: **(A)** I don't think those are the most precise, or even accurate, adjectives to use here — “conventional”, “subcultural”.  **(B)** Also, if you want to, you could always reference the scene from Pink Floyd's _The Wall_ during the Young Lust song.

Answer (score 1):

What does the phrase mean?

One can find the ending phrase in many iterations:

bad girls do or go etc x, y and z

I searched Oxford for the definition of a good girl: = nada!
I searched Oxford for the definition of a good boy: +1.
I searched Oxford for definition of a bad boy: +1.

I searched Oxford for the definition of *bad girl*

> **bad girl**
> Informal (originally US). A woman who defies expected or approved
> standards of conduct, especially one who behaves in a wild,
> rebellious, or sexually provocative manner
> [English Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bad_girl)

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bad%20Girl) citation:

> A girl with many characteristics of assholes or douchebags. They are independent, willful, and unlike good girls do and say as they please as they fear no consequences. The only opinions that matter to them is their opinion of themselves. They challenge the female population and society as they are fierce, refuse to follow trends, and make a name for themselves without conforming to what society sees as 'right for women'.
>
> They aren't looking for trouble, but there is something dangerous about her. Their dark beauty and snarky sense of humor draws men in like moths to a flame. Famous for their spontaneous/ fun/ cunning personality, good looks and brains.
>
> NOT to be confused with skanks, or sluts, or girls who 'drink/ fuck/ and pop pills'
>
> Tend to always be sexier and more alluring than Good girls.
> **Bad girls**: Angelina Jolie, Rihanna, Megan Fox, Blair Waldorf, Natalia Kills, Penelope Cruz

Doubt there is much of a call for:

> good boys to heaven, bad boys go to x, y or Z.

What about going **backstage**?  [Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backstage)  One can make their own assumptions:

> 1 : of, relating to, or occurring in the area behind the stage and
> especially in the *dressing rooms* 2 : of or relating to the *private
> lives* of theater people

What does all this mean? Different strokes for different folks.

Comment: I don't think the OP had a problem with the meaning of "bad girl", I think it was "backstage" that caused the puzzlement, and how that is connected to being a bad (naughty) girl/woman.

Answer (score 1):

In the subculture of people who attend (or historically attended) rock concerts, there is a stereotype - which is true for some people and some bands, but not true for all people/bands.

The stereotype is that these people - typically teenage girls- are attracted to the band, its performers or the glamour of the performance, and go to the concert with the hope of getting the attention of a member of the band and perhaps being invited to their private dressing room behind the stage ("backstage") or their hotel, to have a sexual encounter with them. It could be any band member, or perhaps a specific member they have a "crush" on - perhaps even a member of their crew. It could be more like a "trophy" - being able to boast about it, like an achievement.

An example of the behaviour which gives rise to this stereotype can be seen in videos of "[Beatlemania](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatlemania)", and related behaviour and videos. The same behaviour can be seen among intense fans of many other music bands. Its also seen in other situations where members of the public have an almost fanatical adoration of some public figure who is perceived as erotically desirable or sexual fantasy/trophy material to them.

So "bad girls go backstage" means, that while a "good" girl follows norms and gets the conventional and not-so-special "normal" reward ("goes to heaven"), "bad" girls have more fun by breaking the accepted social norm, and by being wild, and by succeeding in having wonderful and wild encounters "backstage" with famous rock stars - themselves common objects of fantasy. The expression also pokes fun at the idea of "good" girls, who are implied to be compliant but gain less enjoyment from their more usual conduct.

Comment: I agree, except for "subculture" of people who attend rock concerts?

Comment: Groupies comes to mind as a possible term, but the OP possibly isn't that likely to know the term, so best avoided. I also didn't want to use assumptive or pejorative language. There probably is an underground of intense fans for many bands, and perhaps considered in their entirety (it's probably similar across bands) it might not be unreasonable to consider it as forming a subculture?